# How to replace numbers before comma delimiter and autoincrement

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a txt file that looks roughly like this:

```
1,text,text,text
2,text,text,text
3,text,text,text
```

But with a lot more lines, I simply want to replace the number before the first comma with new numbers starting with the number 1000 and have it auto-increment on each line. There are so many lines that it's just not viable to do it manually.

I thought I'd be able to do it quickly with sed or awk, but I'm too much of a noob to get it right. Closest I got was using `sed 's/^[^,]*/1000/'` but that simply replaces the numbers with 1000 and doesn't increment them on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{$1=NR+999}1' yourfile
```

This says:

1. Before processing the file, set the Field Separator and Output Field Separator (FS and OFS) to comma `BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}`
2. Set the first field (`$1`) to the line number (`NR`) plus 999 `{$1=NR+999)}`
3. Print the line `1`

Comment: There's a typo in there `)`

Comment: Slightly shorter: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}($1=NR+999)'`

Comment: Slightly shorter: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}($1+=999)'` (but OP is not really clear on what is currently on 1st column)

Comment: What about: `awk '$1=++i' {O,}FS=, i=999 file`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Clever way to do it.  Can you explain the `OFS`, never seen it done this way.  Can also be written like this: `awk '$1=i++' {O,}FS=, i=1000 file`

Comment: @Jotne: I discovered recently that you can pass variables to awk (without the -v switch), putting them after the script part. `{O,}` is nothing more than a glob alternation expanded by the shell ("O" or nothing). However, it will be interesting to know if this kind of pratice is portable or not (actually I know it works with bash and awk even in POSIX mode).

Answer (score 1):

Associating the new value in the first column with NR is a viable solution.  If you want a bit more flexibility, you might try something like:

```
awk '$1~/[0-9]+/{$1=v++}1' FS=, OFS=, v=1000 input
```